# Localhost Flask app crashes after 413 error

Tags: python, flask, localhost, uwsgi, werkzeug

Okay so I've realized that something weird is happening when I try to upload more than I specified in my `config.py` which is:

```
class Config:
#other configurations
MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH = 10 * 1024 * 1024
```

When I try to upload more than 10 MB, instead of giving me a 413 Error, application just refuses to connect. My error handler:

```
@errors.app_errorhandler(413)
def error_413(error):
    return render_template('errors/413.html'), 413
```

My `run.py`:

```
from flaskblog import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I can see on terminal that I've gotten this error:

```
"POST /foo/bar HTTP/1.1" 413 -
```

Although my app seems to be running on the terminal, I can't access it whatsoever. It's just dead on the browser:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I tried running it on uWSGI, Werkzeug, other browsers, no luck.

Any idea what's happening?

EDIT: I can access after I restart my computer. But I'm still curious why about this happens.
Also I use Cloud SQL with external IP for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay next time I should read documentations more carefully:

> Connection Reset Issue When using the local development server, you
> may get a connection reset error instead of a 413 response. You will
> get the correct status response when running the app with a production
> WSGI server.

from [Flask - File uploads.](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when using the `MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH` configuration.Did you register the blueprint `errors` if yes,Please try removing `app_` from `@errors.app_errorhandler`.Like below:

```py
@errors.errorhandler(413)
def error_413(error):
    return render_template('errors/413.html'), 413
```

If this didn't work try removing the `MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH` line or if you are trying to connect from another device, run your app with the following command `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` and then access it on the other device using your router's ip address which usually looks like `192.168.xxx.xxx` and the port which your app is running on like `192.168.xxx.xxx:<port_of_your_app>`.If this doesn't work it might be an issue with your firewall refusing incoming connections in the port that your app is running on in which case you can run the following command on your terminal `sudo ufw allow <YOUR_PORT>`.